# php script on windows server starts selenium and calls phpunit

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I hope someone can help with this problem, it driving me crazy. I have installed the below on Windows Server 2008 R2:
- selenium server
- PHP
- phpunit

I can start selenium server and execute phpunit scripts manually and all is ok.  They are working great.  But I am trying to automate the whole process and do all of this in a php script.  So, I have produced:

```
<?php
    /* 
        Start the Selenium server with the chrome browser driver in a separate cmd window
        /k =  execute the cmd and then return to initial CMD prompt
    */
echo "\nStart the Selenium Server and pass the Chrome browser as an argument";
    $startSeleniumWithChrome = 'start cmd /k java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Users\*\Automation\requiredFiles\chromedriver.exe" -jar "C:\Users\*\Automation\requiredFiles\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar"';
echo "\nBefore startSeleniumWithChrome";
    exec($startSeleniumWithChrome);
echo "\nAfter startSeleniumWithChrome";

echo "\nBefore START phpunit";
    $executePhpunitCmd = 'start cmd /k phpunit -c phpunit.xml'; 
    exec($executePhpunitCmd);
echo "\nAfter START phpunit";
?>
```

MY PROBLEM:
The exec($startSeleniumWithChrome); above seems to hang. The script will not move past this point.  Does anyone have any idea how I can see what is causing the script to hang?
Thanks
Conor

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `exec()` will wait for the process to end and then return the output. Since selenium will run a headless browser session, it will not end, but run in the background. This is also documented in the Notes section:

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

On Linux you could just pipe the output to `/dev/null`. This will give you instant feedback, but the process will keep running in the background (with the output being ignored):

```
exec($startSeleniumWithChrome . ' /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

I'm not sure if this works on Windows, if not you could just try this:

```
exec($startSeleniumWithChrome . ' &');
```

Alternatively you could try using popen()/pclose() if you want to get some output from the running process.